# How can I create controller instance with params from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I need to create a `controller` instance from another `controller` for using its methods. When I creating

```
c = SomeController.new
c.some_method
```

some_method use `params[]`, and then I have an error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'parameters' for nil:NilClass`.
How can I pass params to the `controller`?

Comment: Sure you need to instantiate another controller within a controller? What you're trying to do?

Comment: yes you can create controller instance but it's not good, instead move `some_method` to model or some other `class`

Comment: I know that sounds strange but I need this. I can't move it to some other class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do it not recommended any framework. You probable have some code that you wanted in multiple controllers. To achieve your desired behavior, extract the common code to library can call that in any controller you want.

Comment: I know that sounds strange but I need this. I can't move it to some other class

Comment: you can set params first before calling method as c.params = params. after that you can call your desired method. @SerhiiBodnaruk

Answer (score 0):

You don't instantiate controllers in Rails - its done by the router when it matches a request to a route.

Its just not done because it violates the way MVC in Rails works - one request = one controller. You also need to pass the entire env hash from rack into the controller for it even work properly.

But really - don't. There are much better ways.

If you need to share a method between controllers there are better ways such as using inheritance:

```
class ApplicationController
  def some_method
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController

end

class BarController < ApplicationController

end
```

Or mixins:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/foo.rb
module Foo
  def some_method
  end
end

class BarController < ApplicationController
  include Foo
end

class BazController < ApplicationController
  include Foo
end
```

If you instead need to move a request from one controller action to another you should be redirecting the user.